# How to get BoxConstraints by using context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to get the constraints by using context in a function(before build method).

In `build()` method, If we use `LayoutBuilder` at the very beginning, it provides the `constraints` that the child can occupy. Then is it possible to get them via `context` directly?

If not, then explain how `LayoutBuilder` provides this `constraints`.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart#L99

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible using only `context`.

Widgets are not able to:

- obtain constraints
- read their position
- read their parents/siblings/...

The only reason that `LayoutBuilder` is able to pass a `BoxConstraint` to the widget tree is that it uses something that is **not** a widget:

`RenderObject`

As such, if your goal is to remove a bit of boilerplate by using `context` directly instead of `LayoutBuilder`, then forget it.

To achieve something similar to `LayoutBuilder` is relatively complex and verbose.